# Quick and Dirty Solution to Load Balancing Batch Jobs

Tags: java, batch-file, load-balancing

We're developing a web app and are coming to the end of development, and the client we're working with has suddenly sprung the fact on us that we will need to be able to handle load balancing.

We have batch jobs running which would need to run on both servers, but we don't want them to overlap.  They are selecting rows from the database, processing the objects, and merging them back into the database.  One of these jobs MUST run at the same time each day, though the others run every n minutes.  We have about a week **at most** to get something working, and it'll become technical debt for us.

My question is: what quick and dirty hacks exist to get this working properly?  We have a SQLServer 2008 instance and are running Java EE 6 on JBoss 5, which will be load balanced between two servers.  We're using Spring 3 and JPA2 backed by Hibernate, and using the stock spring scheduler to schedule and run the jobs.  Help me Obi Wan Kenobi; you're my only hope!

Answer (score 1):

Almost 10 years after this question was asked, I had the same need and the "quickest and dirty-ess" solution for me was a load balancer using shared file system without any master.
[image]

Each worker locks->picks the jobs from the shared file system, independent of other workers. To balance load, each worker sleeps X seconds between each job polling iteration, where X is proportional to load on the worker (in my case load is count of processes started by worker in the background). Thus high load sleeper gives higher probability to other workers to pick up the next job. Worker loops are running under supervisor (linux).
[image]

My use case was execution of sparklyr client-mode jobs on Spark/Hadoop cluster without overloading the edge nodes. It was implemented as a bash script within few hours and then scaled to 3 hosts, and has been stable for some months now - till there is time to invest in a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

on jboss5 u need to use Scheduler API as the simplest solution - the implmentation is built on top of quartz and generally you would user clustered configuration like described here

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering